# .deb repository management software

Tags: ubuntu, debian, repository

I've been searching for an user friendly solution to manage a repository for some custom .deb packages we're using inside my company. I've briefly looked over the tools listed [here](http://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository#Available_Tools), but they seem to me to be just bunch of scripts glued together to do the job (some of them badly documented even).

Is there any "full-blown" solution that:

- has a web interface to allow configuration and inspection of the repository (configure sign keys, distribution names, etc. basically an interface for the common operations you can perform on a repo)
- allows users (based on some ACL) to upload packages to certain distributions
- has hooks for events like "pre-add-package", "post-add-package", etc.

or at least something resembling that?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen [cobbler](https://fedorahosted.org/cobbler/wiki/DebianDeployment) meeting production requirements for redhat and centos (custom repository was necessary). You might want to try it for debian.